# Control Function Parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, parameters, controls

I need to make a function where I can pass a control in the parameters, then check in
a select case statement what control it is and reutrn for every specific control a specific string:

```
Private Function OptionInfoHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) As String
    Select Case sender
        Case sender Is TextBox1
            Return "dsfsdf"
        Case sender Is CheckBox3
            Return "dfsdfsdf"
        Case sender Is RadioButton1
            Return "sfdsfrad"
    End Select
End Function
```

This was my attempt.
But I get these errors:

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: No its not correct, I cannot compile the code. It is underlining the Case sender is TextBox, Case sender is CheckBox etc, and then shows the errors which I've screenshoted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you're question wrong.. then please add some more information on what you want to do ,and also what are you using the return info for . And why it needs to be a function.

Else

You don't need a function for what you want to do.

Just add this code and put the MouseHover event of all controls on it.

Then use the ReturnString for you're return

```
Dim ReturnString As String
Private Sub OptionInfoHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseHover, RadioButton1.MouseHover, CheckBox3.MouseHover
    If sender Is TextBox1 Then
        ReturnString = "TextBox1"
    ElseIf sender Is CheckBox3 Then
        ReturnString = "CheckBox3"
    ElseIf sender Is RadioButton1 Then
        ReturnString = "RadioButton1"
    End If
    MsgBox(ReturnString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `Select Case`, you specify an expression and then a bunch of cases for the value of that expression.  Your code is effectively this:

```
If sender = (sender Is TextBox1) Then
    Return "dsfsdf"
ElseIf sender = (sender Is CheckBox3) Then
    Return "dfsdfsdf"
ElseIf sender = (sender Is RadioButton1) Then
    Return "sfdsfrad"
End If
```

That's obviously not what you intended and doesn't make sense anyway.  Basically, you can't use a `Select Case` statement to test referential equality; only value equality.  That means you can only use it to test the values of `String`s, `Integer`s and the like.  In your case, you would need to use `If`...`ElseIf` statements, i.e.

```
If sender Is TextBox1 Then
    Return "dsfsdf"
ElseIf sender Is CheckBox3 Then
    Return "dfsdfsdf"
ElseIf sender Is RadioButton1 Then
    Return "sfdsfrad"
End If
```

That said, if you want to do something different for each control then why are you using a common event handler in the first place?  It rather defeats the purpose.  You should just use separate event handlers and then you know what the `sender` is in each one without checking.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out aswell!